# Arbitrary scope nesting in Python

Tags: python, syntax, scope

The following python example is from [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=4pgQfXQvekcC&pg=PT673&lpg=PT673&dq=def%20f1():%20x%20%3D%2099%20def%20f2():%20def%20f3():%20print(x)%20f3()%20f2()%20f1()&source=bl&ots=As3wqeG-Qq&sig=7sIUQaHJfyUyBp8avznZspmpX0Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikitjCntrcAhWql-AKHfCsDPYQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=def%20f1()%3A%20x%20%3D%2099%20def%20f2()%3A%20def%20f3()%3A%20print(x)%20f3()%20f2()%20f1()&f=false):

```
def f1():
  x = 99
  def f2():
      def f3():
          print(x)
          print('f3')
      f3()
  f2()
f1()
```

and this is the output:

```
99
f3
```

Why isn't the output the following?

```
99
f3   # from f1()
99
f3   # from f3()
99
f3   # from f2()
```

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf I believe the question is really about the call stack, not scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because as the code is unwrapped it simplifies to:

```
x = 99
print(x)
print('f3')
```

This is the sequence of unwrapping:

```
def f1():
  x = 99
  def f2():
      def f3():
          print(x)
          print('f3')
      f3()
  f2()
f1()
```

becomes

```
  x = 99
  def f2():
      def f3():
          print(x)
          print('f3')
      f3()
  f2()
```

becomes

```
  x = 99
  def f3():
      print(x)
      print('f3')
  f3()
```

becomes

```
  x = 99
  print(x)
  print('f3')
```

which is then what is executed.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the Python scope rules (LEGB). PYthon will look for:

`L`: local variables

`E`: enclosing variables (variables defined in enclosing functions)

`G`: global variables (variables at the zero-indent level)

`B`: built-in variables

**How your program is executed:**

1. `f1` is defined and then `f1` is called
2. When `f1` is called, `x` takes the value of `99`, then `f2` is defined, and then `f2` is called.
3. When `f2`is called, `f3` is defined, and then `f3` is called.
4. When `f3` is called, `x` is printed, and since there is no local `x` in `f3`, it uses the `enclosing` x that is local to `f1`. Then, you are printing exactly the string `"f3"` with the `print` function.
5. Finally, `f3` returns, `f2` returns, `f1` returns, and your program finishes.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the code:

```
def f():
    print(123)
```

which when executed *won't* print anything. `def` is only defining the function - it's not executed until we do `f()`.

Similarly your example only *defines* the inner functions, but only when `f3` is called do the `print` statements execute.